# Does $X\le Y$ imply $\mathbb{E}[X|Z]\le \mathbb{E}[Y|Z]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $X, Y, Z$ be random variables. If $X\le Y$, I wonder if  $$\mathbb{E}[X|Z=z]\le \mathbb{E}[Y|Z=z]$$ holds.

I have a contradiction between math and intuition.

**First, math.** I think math shows that this inequality is correct. Since $X\le Y$, we have $X-Y\le 0$. Then,
$$\mathbb{E}[X-Y|Z=z]=\sum_{x,y} (x-y)p(X=x,Y=y|Z=z)$$
Since $x-y\le0$ and $p(x,y|z)\ge0$, it is clear that $\mathbb{E}[X-Y|Z=z]\le0$ which implies $\mathbb{E}[X|Z=z]\le \mathbb{E}[Y|Z=z]$.

**Second, intuition.** Intuitively, the inequality is incorrect. For example, it is possible that when $Z=z$, the possibility to have $Y=y$ is zero for all $y$. And it is possible that $\mathbb{E}[X|Z=z]$ is positive. In this case, the inequality does not hold.

Is the intuition wrong? or the math wrong? I searched a bit and found a note saying that the inequality holds almost surely. I don't understand why it is almost surely.

Comment: "the possibility to have $Y=y$ is zero for all $y$" - what does it mean? If "possibility" should be "probability", then it's impossible (assuming all distributions are discrete and $P(Z = z) \neq 0$)

Comment: @mihaild Thanks. Now I know that it is impossible that $p(y|z)=0, \forall y$ because $\sum_y p(y|z)=1$.

Comment: @Shiyu when you say $X \leq Y$, do you mean that $$\sup{\mathcal{X}} \leq \inf{\mathcal{Y}},$$ for $X \in \mathcal{X}$ and $Y \in \mathcal{Y}$?

Comment: @the_candyman Yes, that's what I meant. Is the statement $X\le Y$ sloppy? Or is it acceptable to researchers in this area? My expertise is not in this area, so I am not sure about it.

Comment: @Shiyu IMHO, it is a definition which can be easily misunderstood.

Comment: @the_candyman I think I was wrong about $X\le Y$. Now I am reading a book 'A first look at the rigorous probability theory'. On page 44 (second edition), it says that the expectation is order preserving. There $X\le Y$ is defined as $X(\omega)\le Y(\omega)$ for any $\omega\in\Omega$ and $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ is a probability triple. I think this definition is more reasonable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inequality is true for all integrable random variables $X$ and $Y$.

For any $A\in\sigma(Z)$,

$E[E[X\mid Z]1_A]=E[X1_A]\leq E[Y1_A]=E[E[Y\mid Z]1_A].$

A measure-theoretic argument implies that $E[X\mid Z]\leq E[Y\mid Z]$ almost surely.

The reason why the inequality holds almost surely is because the conditional expectation is only defined up to null events. One can propose different conditional expectations which only differ on events of probability $0$.

For example take $Z\sim U(0,1)$ and $X=Z^2$, $Y=Z$.

We have $X\leq Y$ and I can write $E[Y\mid Z]=Z$.

I can also write $E[X\mid Z]=Z^2$ or $E[X\mid Z]=Z^21_{Z\neq1/2}+161361_{Z=1/2}$.

Both these choices for $E[X\mid Z]$ are valid and in both cases I would have $E[X\mid Z]\leq E[Y\mid Z]$ almost surely, but the second choice for $E[X\mid Z]$ would not allow me to say $E[X\mid Z]\leq E[Y\mid Z]$ for all values of $Z$.

Comment: Many thanks. I am studying related topics and noticed that probability is closely related to measure theory, which I am not very familiar with before. Could you explain more on the function $1_{event}$, or suggest some books or articles covering what you mentioned in your answer for beginners? Thanks.

Comment: $1_{event}$ is the indicator random variable of $event$. It takes the value $1$ if we observe $event$ to be true and $0$ otherwise. For example $1_{Z=1/2}$ in the above example would be equal to $1$ if $Z=1/2$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Thanks. Could you also kindly suggest some good references for a systematic introduction on related topics?

Comment: I found a good book entitled “A First Look at Rigorous Probability Theory”

Answer (score 1):

According to your answer to my comment, I suppose that $$X \leq Y$$
stands for

$$\sup{\mathcal{X}} \leq \inf{\mathcal{Y}},$$

where $X \in \mathcal{X}$ and $Y\in \mathcal{Y}$.

For the sake of simplicity, assume that

$$X \in \{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\}$$

and

$$Y \in \{y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_m\},$$

where $x_1 < x_2 < \ldots < x_n$, $y_1 < y_2 < \ldots < y_m$ and 
$$x_n \leq y_1.$$

Then:

$$\mathbb{E}[X|Z=z]=\sum_{x = x_1}^{x_n} x p(X=x,Y=y|Z=z) \leq x_n$$

and

$$\mathbb{E}[Y|Z=z]=\sum_{y = y_1}^{y_m} y p(X=x,Y=y|Z=z) \geq y_1.$$

Therefore, since $x_n \leq y_1$ by hypothesis, then

$$\mathbb{E}[X|Z=z] \leq x_n \leq y_1 \leq \mathbb{E}[Y|Z=z].$$

Finally:

$$\mathbb{E}[X|Z=z] \leq \mathbb{E}[Y|Z=z].$$

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your intuition is wrong. When $Y =0$ and $X\leq Y$, $X$ cannot take positive values.

Comment: The intuition is that $p(y|z)=0$ for all $y$, which I know now is impossible, because $\sum_y p(y|z)=1$